# ID of saved JModelForm

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, model

I am saving a model from controller as mentioned below.

```
$model->save($data);
```

My model save function looks as shown below.

```
public function save($data)
{
    $id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : (int)$this->getState('rev.id');
    $state = (!empty($data['state'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    if($id) {
        //Check the user can edit this item
        $authorised = $user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_customroi.rev.'.$id) || $authorised = $user->authorise('core.edit.own', 'com_customroi.rev.'.$id);
        if($user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_customroi.rev.'.$id) !== true && $state == 1){ //The user cannot edit the state of the item.
            $data['state'] = 0;
        }
    } else {
        //Check the user can create new items in this section
        $authorised = $user->authorise('core.create', 'com_customroi');
        if($user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_customroi.rev.'.$id) !== true && $state == 1){ //The user cannot edit the state of the item.
            $data['state'] = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($authorised !== true) {
        JError::raiseError(403, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));
        return false;
    }

    $table = $this->getTable();
    if ($table->save($data) === true) {
        return $id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

After saving the model in controller (which is working fine), I need to save some associated data for which I need the ID of the saved model. I tried the following hoping one of them will return the ID along with other information but no success so far.

```
$model->getProperties();
$model->getState('rev.id');
```

Getting ID of an model shouldn't be that difficult so I must be missing something basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database driver will add the result back to the Table after saving.

So, something like next should work:

```
$table = $this->getTable();
if ($table->save($data) === true) {
    return $table->id;
} else {
    return false;
}
```